# Increasing an objects instance variable by one with each new object created in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am working on a problem. I had to create a `Boat` class and that boat has-a serial number that increases by 1 each time a new `object` is made. My tests passed for the `createNewSerialNumber()` method but when I test it on the `Boat` object, I keep getting the error that the `AssertionFailed, expecting <2> but was <1> or <7> but was <6>` meaning that the object's serial number is not incrementing by one like it should.

I have gone over static vs not static and thought I was doing it correctly. I even checked it against other similar problems and still the same.
Anyone out there with any guidance?

```
    private int counter =0;
    private static int serialNumber = 0;
    public static int createNewSerialNumber()
    {
        serialNumber++;
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public static int getSerialNumber()
    {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    public Boat(String newMake, Color newColor)
    {
        
        make = newMake;
        color = newColor;
        speed = 0;
        counter++;
        serialNumber = counter;
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `createNewSerialNumber`? And `serialNumber = counter` will assign it a value of 1

Comment: Initially I called the method inside the Boat object so:                                                       public Boat(String newMake, Color newColor)
 {
  
  make = newMake;
  color = newColor;
  speed = 0;
  createNewSerialNumber();
 }

Comment: I also tried serialNumber += counter with couter++. I think I have overthought it a few times now but keep getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the `static` variable should be incremented. The `counter` instance variable should be assigned the incremented value.

```
public Boat(String newMake, Color newColor)
{
    make = newMake;
    color = newColor;
    speed = 0;
    counter = createNewSerialNumber();  
}
```

This way, the first `Boat` instance will have `counter == 1`, the second will have `counter == 2`, and so on.

You should also make the `createNewSerialNumber` method `private`, since `serialNumber` shouldn't be incremented from outside this class. Only the `Boat` constructor should increment it.